# DropDownListFor is not showing in my modal, while my selectListItem isn't null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm trying to put a DropDownList in my PartialView which is showing in a modal.
But, even if my SelectList is populated, nothing appear, on the screen and when I inspect the element.
(By the way, my PartialView is showing other div if I put in comment the DropDownListFor)

I've already tried to debug but I don't get where's the problem...

My PartialView :

```
 <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.SelectedProduit, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
      @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.SelectedProduit, new SelectList(Model.Produits, "Value", "Text"))
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SelectedProduit, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
 </div>
```

My controller :

```
    public IActionResult AddOrEditLup(int id)
    {
        LupViewModel lup = new LupViewModel
        {
            Produits = _ProduitContext.GetProduits()
        };            
        return PartialView("AddOrEditLup", lup);
    }
```

and my LupViewModel :

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Produit")]
    public string SelectedProduit { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Produits { get; set; }
    public LupViewModel()
    {
        Produits = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
```

I just want to show this DropDownListFor, but I don't get why it doesn't want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out solution of your problem:

> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedProduit,
>   model.Produits.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value =
>   x.Id.ToString() }))

Comment: Oh ok, you're creating the SelectListItem with the Item I got in my model.Produits, it seems to be better. But it does not work... I don't get why it doesn't want to appear

Comment: What are properties of Produits class ?

Comment: Porduits is just an IEnumerable<SelectListItem> from my Model, and populated with a list of product in my controller

Comment: Change your controller this way :

LupViewModel model = new LupViewModel();
model.Produits = GetProductList();

Comment: public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetProductList()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> List = new List<SelectListItem>();
            List<ProductListModel> GetProducts = GetProductTypes().ToList(); //your code for fetching product list
            GetProducts.ForEach(c => List.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = c.Product_Name, Value = c.Product_Id.ToString()})); // update your product name with my Product_Name and Product_Id too
            List = List.OrderBy(p => p.Text).ToList();
            return List;
        }

Comment: Please accpet my answer and vote if you find it needful